# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/personalization/1.0

Tags: maven, jsp, aem

While setting up AEM 6.1 plugin in eclipse and importing all the contents from crx got the following error under /libs/foundation/components.

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/personalization/1.0

Code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="personalization" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/personalization/1.0" %>
```

Comment: Do you get this before or after the first compile?